# Is there a way to theoretically concatenate two names to make a variable name that is already defined?

Tags: python

The objective of this code is basically to create dynamically named variables automatically at runtime, more specifically lists then loop through range of values based on how many lists I have then display them out as such. It seems to work when I define the variable I'm printing out as such

```
listNum = int(input("how many lists?: "))
for i in range(listNum+1):
    globals()[f"my_list{i}"] = []

print(my_list0)
```

But when I try to loop through them so that I can display them it doesn't seem to work, giving me an error `NameError: name 'my_list' is not defined`

```
listNum = int(input("how many lists?: "))
for i in range(listNum+1):
    globals()[f"my_list{i}"] = []

for i in range(listNum):
    print(f"{my_list}+{i}")
```

What may I be missing, because i'm trying to concatenate **my_list** with the value in the **range** so it can print out the variable that is there?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why are you not using a list of lists?

Comment: Of course this is theoretically possible. But why do you not use a better data stucture such as a dictionary or nested list?

Comment: when i print, i want to loop through a range of numbers and concatenate it to the **my_list** so it can form a variable like my_list1 and so on. Elaborate on how i would use list of lists?

Comment: You have to access it the same way you defined it: as a dynamically constructed key into the mapping returned by `globals`: `print(globals()[f'{my_list}{i}'])`.

Comment: Defining the list of lists is trivial: `my_lists = [my_list0, my_list1, ...]`, then access `my_lists[0]`, `my_lists[1]`, etc. Once you have that, you can define `my_lists` more directly, without all the unnecessary intermediate names `my_list0` etc.

Answer (score 3):

```
print(f"{my_list}+{i}")
```

is printing a string and the string is formatted from 2 variables: `my_list` which does not exist and `i` which exists. You want

```
print(globals()[f"my_list{i}"])
```

I hope that this is only a theoretical question. Never do this in real code that someone needs to maintain. Having lists and dictionaries is typically enough, like so with lists:

```
manylists = []
for i in range(0, listNum):
    manylists.append([1,2,3])  # adds a list into the list. Tricky ;-)

print(manylists[8])  # make sure you enter a number higher than 8 initially
```

Or with dictionaries:

```
manylists = {}
for i in range(0, listNum):
    manylists[f"list{i}"] = [1,2,3]  # the list has a name in this case

print(manylists["list8"])  # make sure you enter a number higher than 8
```

Comment: How can I use the dictionary in this case?

Comment: @adamadam: added an example

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary keys are pretty much "variable names you can create at runtime":

```py
human_knowledge = {}

for _ in range(5):
    name = input("What is your name? ")
    quest = input("What is your quest? ")
    colour = input("What is your favourite colour? ")
    
    human_knowledge[name + quest] = colour
```